# OpenCV Python video doesnt respond

Tags: python, opencv

I wrote the following code to filter video feed from a camera to only show the bright spot from lights or reflections. When I run it, the window opens up but it wont respond and nothing is shown.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import keyboard

#Starts capturing video in a VideoCapture object called cap
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#While the q button is  not pressed, the while loop runs
while not keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    #ret is a placeholder (not used)
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    #Sets the range of acepted colors in HSV
    whiteRange = np.array([[0, 0, 200], [255, 40, 255]])

    #Blurs the image to remove noise and smooth the details
    gaussianBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5,5), 0)
    #Converts from BGR to HSV to filter colors in the next step
    hsvFrame = cv2.cvtColor(gaussianBlur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    #Filters for white only and turns other colors black
    whiteFilter = cv2.inRange(hsvFrame, whiteRange[0], whiteRange[1])

    #Display the final image
    cv2.imshow('Tape-Detection', whiteFilter)

#Ends the capture and destroys the windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any suggestions would be great too, I'm new to OpenCV Python.

Comment: Could you check if the frames are being captured using `print(ret)` right below `cap.read()`?

Comment: Yep it is capturing them, it prints out a never-ending stream of 'True'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `cv2.imshow()` without `cv2.waitKey()`. The spare cycles while you are waiting are used to update the display.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this fixed it

Comment: No probs - good luck with your project and come back if you get stuck again.